# PhP strip_tags: how do I remove tags that holds a certain attribute

Tags: php, regex, strip-tags

I would like to strip the tags out of my wordpress feed, but keep the paragraphs.

```
strip_tags($content, '<p>' );
```

This works fine but I do not want to keep the paragraphs that deals with image captions... they look like this:

`<p class="wp-caption-text">blah blah blah</p>`

So, how do I strip tags that hold, let's say, class attributes?

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Your requirement can't be done with the `strip_tags` as the PHP Manual says..`This function does not modify any attributes on the tags that you allow using allowable_tags`

Comment: Consider rewording your question -- the way you state your question "how do I strip tags that hold, let's say, class attributes" appears to not actually be what you're asking to do (which is to remove the *elements* with that particular class).

Comment: Thanks. The hardest part is often asking the right question :P

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be to use a DOM parsing library.  `DOMDocument` is built into PHP and works great for DOM manipulation.  `DOMXPath` is good for querying.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//*[not(p)]|.wp-caption-text") as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Note that this also does the work of `strip_tags`.

Comment: Cool, I'll try it out. I'm kind of new to DOM parsing, but think I'll start reworking all my nasty regex as soon as I get a better hold of it. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This wasn't actually the solution to what the OP wanted, however answers the question that was asked.

---

You can't do this with strip_tags directly unfortunately.

You could use DOMDocument, though, then strip_tags after:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($content);
foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName("p") as $p)
{
    foreach($p->attributes as $attr)
        $p->removeAttributeNode($attr);
}
$content = $DOM->saveHTML();

//Uncommenting this will then remove the tag as well.
//$content = strip_tags($content, 'p');
```

Comment: OP: "So, how do I strip tags that hold, let's say, class attributes?" This does not achieve that

Comment: @SamuelCook it does actually. Mistakenly kept the <> from the OP code. The OP question is actually ambiguous -- it states "how do I strip tags" when it actually should read "how do I remove elements with a particular class".

Comment: I changed the ambiguous title :P But, do you know how I set the right encoding? I.e. I get "â€" instead of quotation mark :(

Comment: I sort of figured it out:
`$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'html-entities', 'utf-8');`
`$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`
`$DOM->substituteEntities = TRUE;`